# ORA-06532: Subscript outside of limit

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Pleae help me to understand why Second block is throwing error but first block is running.Both places the limit is lesser than the size declared(41).

```
Declare
  Type typ_int_array IS VARRAY(41) OF NUMBER;
  v_typ_int_array typ_int_array := typ_int_array(10,20,30,40);
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_typ_int_array(1));
  v_typ_int_array.extend(6);
  v_typ_int_array(6) := 60;
END;
```

---

```
Declare
  Type typ_int_array IS VARRAY(41) OF NUMBER;
  v_typ_int_array typ_int_array := typ_int_array(10,20,30,40);
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_typ_int_array(1));
  v_typ_int_array.extend(38);
  v_typ_int_array(38) := 60;    
END;
```

**Exception :**

```
**Error :**
Error report -
ORA-06532: Subscript outside of limit
ORA-06512: at line 6
06532. 00000 -  "Subscript outside of limit"
*Cause:    A subscript was greater than the limit of a varray
           or non-positive for a varray or nested table.
*Action:   Check the program logic and increase the varray limit
           if necessary.
10
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The argument to `extend` is the number of items to *add* to the array, not the final size.

When you add thirty-eight to the original four, you get forty-two, which is definitely greater than 41. Well, it was when I went to school but I'm pretty certain I would have heard about a change like that if they'd enacted it :-)

The first one works because adding six to four only gives you ten, well under the limit of forty-one.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared varray size is 41
Then you already initiate 4 values
Then you extend 38 which means
Already initiative value (4) + extended value (38) =42
It's > 41
So that's the reason.